# Contagion, astrology and witchcraft

Tags: medicine, 19th-century

In 1849, [*The Economist*](https://www.economist.com/books-and-arts/2020/08/01/how-hand-washing-explains-economic-expansion) declared that

> The belief in contagion, like the belief in astrology and witchcraft, seems destined to die out; and as we have got rid of all regulations for consulting the starts or attending to omens before we begin any undertakings, and of all the laws against feeding evil spirits and punishing witches, so we shall no doubt in time get rid of the quarantine regulations that were established from the old belief in contagion.

How widespread in England in the 19<sup>th</sup> century was the idea that contagion is just an “old belief”? Is anyone aware of more texts written around the same time in a similar spirit?

Comment: See [Contingent contagionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingent_contagionism#Contagionists_versus_anticontagionists). "*By the 1840s public health policy, at least in the United Kingdom, had become a battleground between contagionist and anti-contagionist parties. The former, in particular, supported quarantine measures against epidemics (such as the cholera pandemic). The latter opposed quarantines... Public health measures quite typically combined contagionist and anti-contagionist aspects*". Sounds familiar.

Comment: As a case in point -- in *The White Death: A History of Tuberculosis*, Thomas Dormandy quotes a letter from Keats lamenting the difficulty in selling his coach because all the Italians are so backward as to believe that TB is contagious.   The book has more, though naturally concentrated on TB, not contagion in general.